# How to position elements properly regarding different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, mobile, ionic-framework, screen-size

For a mobile app which I develop using Ionic I'm trying to position a label inside the circle of the female and male sign. But the positioning seems quite hard to do with different screen sizes.

This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like]

But once I use a bigger screen it looks like this:

[image: But once I use a bigger screen it looks like this]

For the male sign I used the % unit as often stated here at stackoverflow:
(positioning is absolute)

```
.gender-counter .male label{
  left: 38%;
  top: 28%;
}
```

I've also tried to use vw and vh for the female sign:

```
.gender-counter .female label{
  left: 8.7vw;
  top: 1vh;
}
```

Still same result.

Check out my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/MrFloppy/pen/eJxpGR) for details.

I know there is a way to make a specific design for different screen sizes using @media. But this seems like a total overkill to make one design for so many different sizes.

Is there any better way to do this?

As a side-question:
The buttons should not be squeezed and should keep a perfect circle with all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the labels horizontally you need to add the following to labels

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks! For the female this works like a charm!
But not for the male sign.
I've updated the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/MrFloppy/pen/eJxpGR)
How do I do this when it is not exactly the center of the image?

Comment: You can 'cheat' a littile bit. For the most part same as above but add some negative margin to it. That would be

left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
margin-left: -10px;

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly! :)